# My card to be used is to be cancelled

Tags: grammar

Can somebody please tell me if it is OK to use the phrase "to be" twice in a sentence?

> My card to be used is to be canceled.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. If it is to be cancelled, how can it be 'a card to be used'?

Comment: Oh OK. What if there are two reference points in the future? 
"My card to be used this week is to be canceled next week. "

Comment: Repeating 'to be' like that may be considered not elegant. Perhaps 'My card which is to be used this week will be cancelled next week (or is not valid next week).'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you cannot, it simply does not make sense!

It should be

> the card that I am going to use is to be cancelled

Comment: That's a little puzzling too. Consider 'the train I am going to use is to be cancelled'. If it is to be cancelled, how can you be 'going to use' it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In this context it means that you are going to use it, but you have just been informed that it is going to be cancelled

Comment: The point I am making is that we use the future continuous tense, e.g. 'I **am** going to use...' about an action which we, at the time of speaking or writing, fully expect to carry out. We cannot then immediately (in the same time frame) cancel that. Consider 'the man I am going to have lunch with is dead', 'the bus I am going to use is [to be] cancelled'. If the planned or foreseen action or event is, now, not to take place, we would use a past tense, e.g. 'the man I **was** going to have lunch with'.